# heroku oversized cookie error with express js and discord oauth

Tags: javascript, express, http, heroku, cookies

im not quite sure where to do this because i dont know the direct cause but

i am having trouble with heroku giving me the

`t=error code=H25 desc="HTTP restriction: oversized cookie"` error everytime i try to auth myself with discord oauth. however, this only happens on certain discord accounts. most discord accounts are fine when they login but on a few the 
cookie is oversized.

i cant pinpoint whats causing it, ive tried using less modules with express.js and limiting how much info i need from discord oauth but none of them have worked.

this is based on a discord account error i think. i am not sure where

this is my server code

````
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
//app.use(apiLimiter);
app.use(helmet());
//app.use(sslRedirect());
app.use(session({
  secret: 'sdfhbw45',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    domain : '.ryuwon.dev',
  }
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());```

passport.use(new Strategy({
  clientID: 'y',
  clientSecret: 'x',
  callbackURL: `https://ssx.ryuwon.dev/callback`,
  scope: scopes
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
      return done(null, profile);
  });
}));```
````

i am using passport-discord for my discord auth. any help is really really appreciated. there is little to no info i can find on the web on how to fix this. this only happens when im authing on certain accounts.

Answer (score 0):

issue fixed, it was with the passport-discord module that for some reaosn passes everything in cookies